# How to execute a procedure from time to time in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want my program to

```
ShowMessage('Hello world!');
```

every single minute, how can I do that?

Comment: use timer vlc component

Comment: You need to use a timer component.

See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635214/delphi-ontimer-event-of-my-own-timer-never-happens

Comment: If the user walks away from the keyboard for a coffee then they might have a lot of dialogs to clear when they return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st of all I'd replace ShowMessage() with MessageDlg() function.
With MessageDlg() u can read if dialog window was closed and block application from showing multiple dialog boxes at same time.

Use TTimer component to execute code periodically. Setting interval to 60'000 milliseconds will execute code every minute.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Interval:=60000;
end;
```

Add MessageDlg() code to onTimer event handler of TTimer component. Turn the TTimer exectution off before showing dialog box and back on after dialog box is closed.

```
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
Timer1.Enabled:=false;
if MessageDlg('test', mtConfirmation, [mbOK], 0)<>0 then
  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
```

Comment: This does something different than the question asks. Anyway, what do you mean by *"With MessageDlg() u can read if dialog window was closed .."* ? It's not what you have given an example of I suppose, since you can do the same with `ShowMessage`. Additionally, you can read `Application.Modal...` properties with `ShowMessage`, which is better - you don't have to disable the timer.

Comment: MessageDlg is not special. It's just like any other modal dialog. I posit that part of your answer belies a lack of clarity.

Comment: I took above comment in concideration: "If the user walks away from the keyboard for a coffee then they might have a lot of dialogs to clear when they return – David Heffernan Apr 21 '14 at 22:34",   thats why I picked MessageDlg instead of ShowMessage. MessageDlg is a function that returns value of modal window button pressed. I could make MessageDlg('test', mtConfirmation, [mbOK], 0)=mrOK but if you have more buttons in MessageDlg than just [mbOK] you have to check for all of em beeing pressed. 0 is the value before any button was pressed to close the MessageDlg and is equivalent of mrNone.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`TTimer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer) component and the `OnTimer` Event. The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TTimer) includes a set of sample projects of how use this component.